How to combine vscode tasks of sub folders in a multi-root workspace?
I have a setup where multiple projects are depending on outputs of each other, each project is independent (so it owns its own tasks).
I want to create a Meta Task, which will build project a and install it in project b.
Here is a simplified example:
{
  "folders": [
    {
      "path": "ProjA"
    },
    {
      "path": "ProjB"
    },
    {
      "path": "."
    }
  ],
  "settings": {},
  "tasks": {
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "label": "run all",
        "dependsOn": [
          "build-a",
          "build-b"
        ],
      }
    ]
  }
}

with a structure like this:
├───test.code-workspace
├───ProjA
│   └───.vscode
│        └───tasks.json
└───ProjB
    └───.vscode
         └───tasks.json

Where both subprojects have tasks (example, same for b)
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "build-a",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "echo 'Building A'",
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "detail": "This command will build project A",
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
  ]
}

The above example returns:
ctivating task providers all
Couldn't resolve dependent task 'build-a' in workspace folder 'file:///c%3A/Users/K0IN/Desktop/test/test.code-workspace'
Couldn't resolve dependent task 'build-b' in workspace folder 'file:///c%3A/Users/K0IN/Desktop/test/test.code-workspace'

And prefixing it with ProjA: and ProjB: did not work.
